# Publishing an approval workflow

Tags: 2013, workflow

I have SharePoint 2013 installed and I am trying to publish my own modified approval workflow.

I would like the workflow to be accessable within the selection below when choosing a workflow to use within the document library.

[image: Workflow selection]

I used SharePoint designer on the SharePoint server (i opened the site I am interested in) and copied and modified the globally reusable work flow named

> Approval - SharePoint 2010

which created a Reusable workflow named

> Approval - Controlled Documents

[image: Created workflow]

If I left click on this I can see that publish appears within the ribbon but if I click this after a few minutes I get the following error which keeps coming up even after I clear it.

[image: Error message]

I have tried looking for a simple guide on the steps I can take to create a simple workflow and deploy it but I cant see one that fits my needs.  Am I missing a step or cant it be done?

Comment: Does the error happens when you create a simple workflow? Try creating one that just's logs 'Hello World' to workflow history list (ie. Log to hitstory-->End Workflow) and try to publish it.

Comment: Yes that worked.

Comment: Hmm not sure then why are you getting this error. Normally i create Approval workflows from scratch. Try this guide for approval WF creation and does it work for you. http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2013/02/25/5-steps-to-enhance-sharepoint-2010-approval-workflow-aspx/

Comment: I thought about that but when I try to find 'Approval workflow task (en-US)' under step 1 its not listed.

Answer (score 0):

After trying numerous suggestions found online to resolve this I was getting nowhere.

Another user in my business needed to reboot the SQL server we use for SharePoint databases due to a back up issue we were having.  This resolved the problem. Works fine now.